# how do i use persian IranNastaliq font with iTextSharp

Tags: fonts, itext, persian

when i was se irannastaliq font all the text was show me wrong
i send you sample scource program
and image of pdf that program was create and the image of pdf i want to create but cant
thank you for your attentions

[1] http://www.mediafire.com/view/wftudo7ydhjrs58/pdf_itextsharp_create.png "Now"

example project :
[2] http://www.mediafire.com/download/ijod1hnzst0c9p9/Example.zip

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know iTextSharp is not able to process GSUB of complex fonts.

- More info here: [Making iText work with Indic scripts](http://palashray.com/making-itext-work-with-indic-scripts/)

Comment: It's indeed not supported yet. It's on our roadmap for next year (2014).

Comment: Per http://www.microsoft.com/typography/OpenTypeDev/arabic/intro.htm cursive positioning is done on GPOS. See an example http://jsfiddle.net/UmKdr/embedded/result/ to see why it needs positioning.

Answer (score -1):

First put your `.TTF` font file into the root path for ease of access in code, then create a new font `object` by this code:

```
// this code is for VB
FontFactory.Register(Server.MapPath(".") + "/IranNastaliq.ttf")
Dim Mitra As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Mitra", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H)
Mitra.Size = 11
```

the create a new `FontSelector` `object` and add your font to it as seen below:

```
Dim fontSelector = New FontSelector()
fontSelector.AddFont(Mitra)
```

and then create new `PdfPCell` `object`

```
Dim contentCell = New PdfPCell With {.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_LTR}
```

and finally use from this code to apply font:

```
contentCell.Phrase = fontSelector.Process(row(i).ToString())
```

**NOTE**
If your coding language is `C#`, you can use from [this](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) online tool to convert all of above code to `C#`.

Comment: If you found a problem with above code, leave a comment here.

Comment: his question is about the `IranNastaliq.ttf` font. iTextSharp is not able to read its GSUB correctly.

Comment: I'm tested it for `Mitra.ttf` and it works properly, What is the GSUB, please?

Comment: It's used for rendering of complex fonts like `IranNastaliq.ttf`. http://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/gsub.htm

Comment: my problem with IranNastaliq font